# How much do we save - interest rate problem

Tags: finance, economics

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

> How much do we save during 5 years by routinely saving 50€ at the end
>   of each month, with annual interest rate of 6% and a continuous
>   compounding? After what time do we save 50 000€?

My calculation is $50*(1+0,06)^{60}$, but my solution is not correct. Could you help me?

Thanks

Comment: Your answer has three problems.  First, it only reflects saving $50$ once at the start, not every month.  Second, it allows for $6\%$ interest per month, not per year.  Third, it ignores the continuous compounding.

Comment: What is the definition of continuous interest?

Comment: @RossMillikan Thanks. I can fix the problems, but how come I ignore the continuous compounding? I thought that's the formula for the continuous compound.

Comment: @Keen-ameteur Sorry, I meant continuous compounding.

Comment: Because you took powers of $1.06$, which would pay $6\%$ interest at discrete intervals.  The exponent $60$ says there are $60$ intervals.

Comment: @RossMillikan $50*12*(1+0,06)^{5}$ I now have it like this. But I still don't understand what's wrong about wrong with $1,06$

Comment: If you got $6\%$ interest compounded annually for $5$ years, the account would multiply by $1.06^5$.  If you got $0.5\%$ per month the account would multiply by $1.005^{60}$.  Here you are getting it compounded faster than every second.  For one month it then multiplies the account by $e^{0.005}\approx 1.00501252$

Comment: @RossMillikan so if it's for 1 month, then for 5 years it will be $e^{0.005*12*5}?$

Comment: That is correct.  It comes from the laws of exponents.  If it is a factor $e^{0.005}$ for one month, it is $(e^0.005})^{12}=e^{12\cdot 0.005}$ for one year

Answer (score 1):

The mathematical answer:

Let $a_n$ be the amount of euros you save by the end of $n$ months. Thus $a_0 = 0$, and for every $n \geq 1$, one has: $$a_n = 1.005 a_{n - 1} + 50.$$ Explanation for the recurrence relation: an annual interest rate of $6\%$ means your money increases by $0.5\%$ at the end of every month, and then you save an extra $50$ euros.

We then solve this recurrence formula: $$a_n + 10000 = 1.005 a_{n - 1} + 10050 = 1.005(a_{n - 1} + 10000).$$ Hence if we define $b_n:=a_n + 10000$, then we have $b_0 = 10000$ and $b_n = 1.005b_{n - 1}$. It is then clear that after five years (i.e. $60$ months), we will have $b_{60} = 1.005^{60} \times 10000 = 13488.5015\cdots$.

Therefore, we have $a_{60} = b_{60} - 10000 = 3488.5015\cdots$. This is the amount of money you have by the end of five years.

---

However!

Euros don't have a unit smaller than $0.01$ euro. Hence in reality the bank should decide how to round to integers.

Assume that the bank rounds to the nearest integer cents. Let $A_n$ be the amount of CENTS you save by the end of $n$ months. Then the formula goes like: $$A_n = round(1.005 A_{n - 1}) + 5000,$$ where $round(x)$ is the nearest integer to $x$. If you calculate $A_{60}$, you will get $348847$.

Therefore you get $3488.47$ euros by the end of five years.

YOU LOSE ABOUT $3$ CENTS!

---

What's worse is: the bank could (and usually will) round DOWN to the nearest integer!

In that case, you only get $3488.14$ euros by the end of five years.

YOU LOSE ABOUT $36$ CENTS!!!

---

EDIT: about how to solve the recurrence formula in the mathematical answer.

This is called "fixed point method". A priori, we would like to find a number $M$, so that when we define $b_n$ as $a_n + M$, we get the easier recurrence formula $b_n = 1.005 b_{n - 1}$.

Therefore we should have $a_n + M = 1.005(a_{n - 1} + M)$, or $a_n = 1.005 a_{n - 1} + 0.005M$. Compare this to our original formula, we immediately see that $0.005M$ should be equal to $50$, hence $M = 10000$.

Comment: Thanks! I don't understand where is the 10 000 from.

Comment: I just googled continuous compounding, which it says is $V(t)=V_0 e^{i\cdot t}$. So isn't $a_{n+1}=50+a_n\cdot e^{1.06}$?

Comment: This does not account for continuous compounding.  The $1.005$ factor should be higher

Comment: @Keen-ameteur:  as the time is in months, it should be $e^{1.005}$

Comment: When people say "annual interest rate", it is an interest rate which is linearly stretched to one year period. Hence "annual interest rate of $6\%$" will be the same as $0.5\%$ per month.

Comment: That is correct, so $1.005$ would be the correct factor for monthly compounding.  It is not correct for continuous compounding.

Comment: but where is the 10 000 from?

Comment: @Peter See my update of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your interest is nominally $0.5\%$ per month.  When that is compounded continuously the balance is multiplied by $e^{0.005} \approx 1.00501252$  To save typing, we will call that $r$.

There are opportunities to be off by $1$ in a problem like this.  We will start at month $0$ and assume the deposits are made at the start of the month.  We take the question to be how much money you have at the start of month $60$ before you make the deposit.

The first $50$ you deposit compounds for $60$ months, so at the end is worth $50r^{60}$.  The second $50$ you deposit compounds for $59$ months, so at the end is worth $50r^{59}$  This continues, so at the end you have $$\sum_{i=1}^{60}50r^i$$
This is a geometric series, with sum $$50\frac{r^{61}-1}{r-1}\approx 3557.34$$
To find the number of months to reach $50000$ we write
$$50000=50\frac{r^{n+1}-1}{r-1}\\
1000(r-1)=r^{n+1}-1\\
(\log(1000(r-1)+1)=(n+1)\log r\\
n+1\approx 358.77$$
So it takes about $358$ months to save $50000$

Comment: Why you put $n+1$ (or 61 for this case) in the exponent of $r$? During 5 years payments are made at the end of each month, therefore, I guess overall 60 payments.

Comment: It is the formula for the sum of a geometric series. The exponent is increased by $1$ compared to the last term.

Comment: If I understand the problem clearly, the first payment, which is paid at the end of the first month, become $50 \times e^{59r}$ at the end of the 12th month of the 5th year, the second payment become $50 \times e^{58r}$, and the last payment is $50$. Therefore, we have the following series $50 \times (e^{59r}+e^{58r}+...e^{r}+1)$, hence the sum of this geometric series is $50\times \frac{e^{60r}-1}{e^{r}-1}$. Am I wrong?